# Concatenate ListBox selected Items

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listbox

I have a listBox in WinForms .NET 4.5. I keep getting 'NULL' exception on insert and I don't know why. I have `TWEAK` as a `.dbml` from `tbl_Tweak` complete with a dataset. I am missing something somewhere and have failed to find what or where. I'm hoping fresh, experienced eyes can shed some light here. Here's the relevant code.

Insert Method:

```
public void InsertOrUpdateTweak(string recipename, string batchID, DateTime dtpTweak, int tempTweak, double specificGravityTweak, string tweakBox, string cbEventItems, int r_ID, string arrr)
        {
            TWEAKDataContext tdc = new TWEAKDataContext();
            if (dirtyTweak == true)
                try
               {
                GetEvents();

                tbl_Tweak log = new tbl_Tweak();
                log.recipename = recipeName;
                log.batchID = batchID;
                log.dtpTweak = DateTime.Now;
                log.tempTweak = tempTweak;
                log.specificGravityTweak = specificGravityTweak;
                log.tweakBox = tweakBox;
                log.cbEventItems = cbEventItems;

                tdc.tbl_Tweak.InsertOnSubmit(log);
                tdc.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;  //<== This is where it breaks
            }
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have not loaded and/or saved the current recipe data");
            }
                finally
                {
                    tdc.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
    }
```

GetEvents method where I try to put the selected items from listbox into a string:

```
public string GetEvents()
{
        string[] arrr = new string[listBoxEvents.Items.Count];
        listBoxEvents.SelectedItems.CopyTo(arrr, 0);
        cbEventItems = string.Join("-", arrr);
        return cbEventItems;
}
```

I have searched SO and found several variations which I show below:

```
public string[] GetEvents()
{
String[] cbEventItems = new String[listBoxEvents.SelectedItems.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < totalEvents; i++)
{
   var arrr = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, listBoxEvents.SelectedItems.Cast<string>());
}
return arrr;
}
```

and...

```
public string[] GetEvents()
{
string[] arrr = new string[listBoxEvents.SelectedItems.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < listBoxEvents.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
arrr[i] = listBoxEvents.SelectedItems[i].ToString();

return arrr;
}
```

and also...

```
public string GetEvents()
{
    List<string> arrr = new List<string>(listBoxEvents.SelectedItems.Count);
    foreach (string listitem in listBoxEvents.SelectedItems)
    {
        cbEventItems = string.Join("-", arrr);
    }
    return cbEventItems;
}
```

Comment: Looks like there may be confusion having a method param and field variable both called cbEventItems.  Strings are immutable which may also be causing an issue.  Try removing the cbEventItems param from the InsertOrUpdateTweak method signature and give that a go

Comment: Add a formal answer and I'll +1 ya. Thanks very much. I feel like a n00b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there may be confusion having a method param and field variable both called `cbEventItems`. Strings are immutable which may also be causing an issue. Try removing the `cbEventItems` param from the `InsertOrUpdateTweak` method signature and give that a go.

Also seeing as the `GetEvents` method returns a string, I would create a method variable and then use that to make the code more readable.

```
public void InsertOrUpdateTweak(string recipename, string batchID, DateTime dtpTweak, int tempTweak, double specificGravityTweak, string tweakBox, int r_ID, string arrr)
        {
             ...
             string eventItems = GetEvents();
             ...
             log.cbEventItems = eventItems;
             ...
        }
```